# Web API 304 'Not Modified' response error how to ignore in Angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I am facing little issue, My Web API returns me 304 'Not Modified' response when there is no change in data being sent for update, and my application has implemented error pages, which redirects me to error page. I want this not to be appeared as error instead this should be ignored.

kindly help me how to ignore this response using HTTP interceptors. Following is code written that intercepts HTTP responses and then redirects me to specific page based on error, I need to ignore 304 response here:

```
myApp.factory('httpErrorResponseInterceptor', ['$q', '$location',
  function ($q, $location) {
      return {
          response: function (responseData) {
              return responseData;
          },              

          responseError: function error(response) {

              switch (response.status) {
                  case 401:                          
                      $location.path(baseUrl + 'Account/Login');
                      break;
                  case 403:
                      $location.path(baseUrl + '403');
                      break;
                  case 404:
                      $location.path(baseUrl + '404');
                      break;
                  case 405:
                      $location.path(baseUrl + '405');
                      break;
                  case 500:
                      $location.path(baseUrl + '500');
                      break;
                  case 503:
                      $location.path(baseUrl + '503');
                      break;
                  case 408:
                      $location.path(baseUrl + 'timeout');
                      break;
                  default:
                      $location.path(baseUrl + 'error');
              }

              return $q.reject(response);
          }
      };
}
]);
```

Comment: Show us your "application has implemented error pages, which redirects me to error page" .. Basically you can catch and check 304 status and do if else to ignore that.

Comment: HTTP interceptor I am using and I have to ignore response here.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution to ignore the 304 'Not Modified' error response by writing this code:

```
//ignore 304-'Not Modified' response
if (response.status === 304) {
   return $q.resolve(response);
}
```

and the complete solution will be as follows:

```
smartBizzApp.factory('httpErrorResponseInterceptor', ['$q', '$location',
  function ($q, $location) {
      return {
          response: function (responseData) {
              return responseData;
          },              

          responseError: function error(response) {

              //ignore 304-'Not Modified' response
              if (response.status === 304) {
                  return $q.resolve(response);
              }

              switch (response.status) {
                  case 401:                          
                      $location.path(baseUrl + 'Account/Login');
                      break;
                  case 403:
                      $location.path(baseUrl + '403');
                      break;
                  case 404:
                      $location.path(baseUrl + '404');
                      break;
                  case 405:
                      $location.path(baseUrl + '405');
                      break;
                  case 500:
                      $location.path(baseUrl + '500');
                      break;
                  case 503:
                      $location.path(baseUrl + '503');
                      break;
                  case 408:
                      $location.path(baseUrl + 'timeout');
                      break;
                  default:
                      $location.path(baseUrl + 'error');
              }

              return $q.reject(response);
          }
      };
}
]);
```